# Is this a varnish hit?

Tags: magento2, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am having an issue with Varnish installed with Magento 2, I have followed this tutorial https://slack-redir.net/link?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.techrepublic.com%2Farticle%2Fhow-to-speed-up-apache-with-varnish-http-cache%2F

I used the next command :

```
curl -I localhost/folder1/folder2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2018 22:23:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 16 Jun 2017 15:47:07 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
X-Varnish: 131250
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
ETag: W/"2c39-55215b29954a5-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
```

I normally see in examples that it should have a HIT but I cannot see it, maybes it is badly configured, also when I click a link on my site it will take 6s, then I click on same link and same amount of time so this means it might not be working

My files:

File /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

File 000-default.conf:

```
etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:8080>
blablablabl
</VirtualHost>

/etc/default/varnish
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
```

File  /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/reload-vcl
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

porst.conf file

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
Listen 8080
#blablabla
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a cache hit.

You can see if cache was hit by checking value of `X-Varnish: 131250`. Single number is a cache miss, two numbers, e.g. `X-Varnish: 131250 12345` is a cache hit.

You need to download special Magento VCL file from Magento admin, not use the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify cache HIT or MISS by adding some code in sub vcl_deliver section of /etc/varnish/default.vcl.

```
if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.Cache-Tags = "HIT";
}
else {
    set resp.http.Cache-Tags = "MISS";
}
```

1. add the above code in vcl_deliver of /etc/varnish/default.vcl.
2. reload/restart varnish.
3. Curl -I your request
4. Look for Cache-Tags in response header.

Method 2:

You can issue a command in varnish server and check the requests are hit or miss

sudo varnishncsa -F '%U%q %{Varnish:hitmiss}x'

If you issue above command and access the website it will show you it's a miss or hit in the command line.

Comment: Just leaving this here: https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/using-obj-hits

clearly not worth an answer on its own, but I feel I have to fight this snippet as much as I can :-)

Comment: @GuillaumeQuintard Thanks Bro. That's the right way, well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are done with your Varnish setup, you can verify varnish hit by the following method:

Go to your Magento front-end -> inspect the page by right-clicking mouse -> go to network tab at inspect -> clear the inspect console.

Reload the page URL once again by selecting the URL of Magento, and you will see the details like cache hit.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30200083)

Comment: @Khaleel The text of the link is the essential part of the answer.  If the link breaks the answer is still usuable.

Answer (score 0):

X-Varnish: 131250

If its a hit then you will find two values.
One of the value will the the values associated with previous request that was cached and used to deliver cache this time.

A single after X-Varnish means this is a miss.